# PHP Multiple Day Event Calendar

Tags: php

I have this code which generates a PHP calendar with events pulled from a MY SQL database:

```
<?php

/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

$month = (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

if($month < 10)
$month = '0'.$month;

/* draw table */
$calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

/* table headings */
$headings = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

/* days and weeks vars now ... */
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,0,$year));
$days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_this_week = 1;
$day_counter = 0;
$dates_array = array();

/* row for week one */
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

/* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
endfor;

/* keep going with days.... */
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;
        if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
            foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['pet_name']. '<br>'. $event['booking_period']. '</div>';
            }
        }
        else {
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
        }
    $calendar.= '</div></td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
endfor;

/* finish the rest of the days in the week */
if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    endfor;
endif;

/* final row */
$calendar.= '</tr>';

/* end the table */
$calendar.= '</table>';

/** DEBUG **/
$calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
$calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

/* all done, return result */
return $calendar;
}

/* get all events for the given month */
include 'functions/connect.php';
$month = str_pad($month,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$events = array();
$query = "SELECT bb_Clients.pet_name, bb_Bookings.booking_period, DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%e') AS start_date FROM bb_Bookings INNER JOIN bb_Clients ON bb_Bookings.client_id=bb_Clients.client_id WHERE start_date LIKE '$year-$month%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('cannot get results!');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$events[$row['start_date']][] = $row;
}

$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));

echo '<h2>'. $monthName .' '. $year .'</h2>';
echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
?>
```

At the moment I am just echoing the booking period on each cell that has an event but I would like to display each event on each day that it runs but I just cannot work out how to do it.

My table has a start date, end date and booking period so I was thinking along the lines of using the booking period value to count the number of days that the event should be displayed but as each event is generated individually I don't know how this would work.

Another idea I had was using the BETWEEN operator to say something like "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE $list_day BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date"

Or maybe there is a simpler way to do it?

(P.S I'm well aware I am using insecure PHP code to pull the data from a database but this is all running locally so it doesn't matter currently).

Comment: simple precision for for future beginners reading this: a local server is not secure per se, it is as long as your computer is secure, in a session with a password, and the right settings

Comment: the code shown looks like it's doing what you want on first look. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You guys are quick! I'm not explaining myself very well, it's displaying events no problem but I want each event that lasts more than one day to display on each day that the event runs for - does that make sense? At the moment it is only displaying the event on the start date of the event.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?